# Static definition lists

Tags: c++

I need to create definition lists in C++ that would describe SQL tables. For the moment I'm doing it like this, as it does not really need to be a real object, and it is rather convenient to initialize this way:

```
namespace Table_name
{
    static ColumnList Cols("Table_name");
    static const Column Id        ("Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY", Cols);
    static const Column Col_name  ("Col_name TEXT", Cols);
}
```

(outer namespaces, `using` etc omitted)

I pass Cols to each constructor so that each Column is registered in the list. I use it both as `Table_name::Col_name` or as `Table_name::Cols` to get a list. For the moment it worked pretty well, but I realized that there can be some issues due to multi-threaded access to those static variables which can eventually occur. Or are those issues only related to local static variables?..

How can I re-work this to make it safe/better and still have a similarly convenient definition and access to the columns variables and their list? I expect each column to be defined at a single place, so enums, "normal" variables etc wouldn't work. Also, do you think the use of macros like `DEF_COL(Col_name, "...");` would be appropriate in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use singleton for this to be sure that you don't have any problem related to undefined order of static initializations

also you can check [MySql++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/) library to check how they resolve table structure definition problem

Comment: I doubt that using singletons I could have that simple definitions of lists... I've checked MySql++'s SSQLs, they achieve this using macros `// The following is calling a very complex macro`, so this answers my question if macros are appropriate :) I need something way simpler, but thanks for the references anyways.

Comment: yeah, macros is commonly used in such cases. have a look at Boost Preprocessor (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to simplify your task. this library provides support for really complex macros

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the necessary synchronisation inside the objects; however unless your table definitions actually change at runtime, these are automatically MT safe.

Comment: I thought there could be initialization problems with MT, but no problems within the same compilation unit? By the way, I just thought that I will need that definition in different compilation units, so this won't work and I'll have to find something else anyway :\

Comment: Synchronisation problems happen because one thread is reading data while the other is writing to it, leading to an inconsistent view. If your data never changes, there is no concurrency issue. If the data changes, place a lock next to it.

Comment: @Simon: Sorry I was confused, actually what I meant was this static initialization order problem http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14 which is not related to MT but might become a problem in my case as I might want to use this description to initialize other static variables...

Comment: That is only a problem across translation units, and only if you really use data inside the objects. If you just store a pointer to the other object, it doesn't matter that the object isn't initialized yet, as long as you do not dereference the pointer before `main()` starts.